# Parameter returns different value every compile

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I got an assignment from school to create a single array from 2 different arrays and to return the combined array organized.

example:

```
arr a[] = {"ace"};
arr b[] = {"bdf"};
```

required result:

```
arr x[] = {"abcdef"};
```

So far I managed to combine the two and re-order them, but every once in a while when I'm compiling the code, it returns a different value at the end of my array (var `p` in my code).

The code I wrote:

```
int main() {

    char a[] = { "1D5"};
    char b[] = { "+J6" };
    int size_a = sizeof(a);
    int size_b = sizeof(b);
    char *p = NULL; //setting the pointer for the start of the array as null
    int total_arr_size = size_a + size_b;
    int index = 0;

    p = (char*)malloc((total_arr_size-1) * sizeof(char));

    if (!p) {
        printf("Allocation error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (index <= total_arr_size-2)
    {
        if (index < size_a && a[index] != '\0') {
                p[index] = a[index];
                index++;
                continue;
        }

        if (index < (size_a + size_b) - 2 ) {
            p[index] = b[index-size_a+1];
            index++;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    printf("total string before sorting - %s \n", p);

    int i, j;
    int n = total_arr_size - 2;
    int temp;


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (p[i] > p[j]) {
                temp = p[i];
                p[i] = p[j];
                p[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("String after sorting  - %s \n", p);

    free(p);
    p = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like `p` to return the value `+156DJ`.

Answer (score 1):

You make your life too difficult. The following is a lot simpler:

```
int main() {

    char a[] = { "1D5"};
    char b[] = { "+J6" };
    int len_a = sizeof(a)-1;
    int len_b = sizeof(b)-1;
    char *p;
    int index = 0;

    if (!(p = malloc(len_a + len_b + 1))) {
        printf("Allocation error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<len_a; i++, index++)
        p[index]= a[i];

    for (int i=0; i<len_b; i++, index++)
        p[index]= b[i];

    p[index]= '\0';

    printf("total string before sorting - %s \n", p);

    // ....
```